# Am I following a good design thought process? Is the Abp framework overkill?

Tags: design, design-patterns, dependency-injection, abstraction, project-structure

As I finish one project and start another, I have a small time window to come up with an architecture for the new. I am coming from the following design:

- **Web application**
  *Receives domain models & DTOs, Sends DTOs*
  application configuration, application-specific DTOs+mapping, application-specific services, & controllers)
- **Core library**
  *Receives entity models, Sends domain models & DTOs*
  domain models+mapping & repositories, entity mappings, DTOs+mapping & services, vendor-specific interface implementations like ASP.NET Identity, anything else we want
- **Data library**
  *Receives input from database adapter (ODAC in this case), Sends entity models*
  entity models, specialized company data context wrapper, useful code representations of schema, extensions for parsing response from database
- **Infrastructure library**
  *Receives nothing, Sends nothing*
  Common interfaces, adapters, wrappers, extensions, and other things used in all projects

These layers were not initially segregated but became so when things got messy. Each segregation took significant refactoring time. Even once all were segregated, there were still some design issues:

- **Tight coupling with vendor implementations like Castle Windsor, AutoMapper, and NLog**
- **Awkwardness and difficulty of generic repository implementations**
- **Duplication of (container, action, etc) logic in applications**
- **Difficulty determining the order in which processes flow & services should be called**

As I see it, the final project structure was more than adequate to support a well-designed architecture. The final product, however, was not designed as well as planned. So I'd like to start out with a more definite architecture this time.

The big change would be to abstract out *every substantial implementation* so that direct calls to things like AutoMapper or NLog are unnecessary. This would require a commitment to depdency injection and implementation of some DI system and/or IoC container. Abstraction will require avoidance of direct inter-layer dependencies, which results in a more granular project structure.

The granularity is helpful to someone at my modest skill level. It forces me to consider where each new component belongs. The problem is that I may not know the optimal set of buckets  (taxonomy of projects and their components) to standardize.

[The `Abp` library](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate) seems like a promising way to get started. It provides [so much abstraction](http://www.aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/NLayer-Architecture) that a direct dependency on `Abp` would be at least 1-to-1 with any structure I could design. It would definitely provide a solid foundation and course for development.

My main concern with implementing `Abp` is the potential for over-engineering and/or wasted time implementing *such* a rigid framework.

My first question is:

- **Is it worth it to use `Abp`? How is that based on personal experience, if at all?**

Given that it *is* worthwhile to embrace `Abp`, I would also like to know:

- **How should `Abp` be integrated into my project? Should I produce a mirror project structure that includes the corresponding base `Abp` version for each `Abp`-defined layer?**

Comment: At the very least, studying the ABP would provide valuable insight into how these architectures work.  Just make sure you don't [run out of oxygen](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000018.html).